# Getting "Unrecognized message version" exception attempting to call WCF service

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I have a WCF service that works locally and previously worked (prior to minor changes) on a separate server.  It now throws an "Unrecognized message version" CommunicationException.  What might be causing this?

In troubleshooting I've found that it's happening somewhere within the WCF "magic" on the server before it resolves to use the custom binding defined for it.

The server itself has had some monkeying around done on it lately to add SSL and change host names so I'm wondering if there's something server-specific happening between IIS (7.5) finding the service and my code getting called.

My services inherit from a base class that includes a simple Ping method that just returns success once contacted.  This has worked on a all other internal server deployments, but even calling this method now give the unrecognized message version.

Calling code just uses a VS-generated Service Reference to create an instance then call it:

```
        var MyService = new MyNamespace.MyServiceClient();
        var result = MyService.Ping();
```

**Update**
The stack trace (no InnerException exists) makes me wonder if it's SOAP-related:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize, String contentType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception& requestException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Lenderprise.WebServiceHost.Test.LLSSTitleSearch.ITitleSearch.Ping()
   at Lenderprise.WebServiceHost.Test.LLSSTitleSearch.TitleSearchClient.Ping() in D:\LLN\DEV\LenderPrise\WebServices\TitleSearchWebServiceHost.Test\Service References\LLSSTitleSearch\Reference.cs:line 138
   at Lenderprise.MainWindow.RunAsLibraryButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in D:\LLN\DEV\LenderPrise\WebServices\TitleSearchWebServiceHost.Test\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 91
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty niche case here:  We have a load balancer (F5) that also manages the SSL certs.  Requests coming in looked to be getting forwarded to the server correctly, but also were redirecting back to itself as well.  I'm not network engineer enough to know all the details but it was F5 configuration not WCF.